# extract specific value by matching name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

name="xx_01"

data_1<- data.frame(name=c("xx_01","xx_02","xx_03"),
start_time=c("2015-01-06 00:01:00", "2015-01-07 05:01:01","2015-01-08 10:01:02"),
end_time=c("2015-01-07 00:01:00", "2015-01-08 05:01:01","2015-01-09 05:01:02"))

data_1$start_time <- as.POSIXct(data_1$start_time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
data_1$end_time <- as.POSIXct(data_1$end_time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

How can I extract the start and end time for any given name that matches the name column in data_1? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the object name ('name') of string is same as the column name, we can escape (`!!`) to force it to check for the object in the global env instead of the column in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
data_1 %>% 
  filter(name == !! name) %>% 
  select(-name)
#        start_time            end_time
#1 2015-01-06 00:01:00 2015-01-07 00:01:00
```

Comment: @sler You can do assignment `data_2 <- data_1 %>% filter(name ...`